# How/when can categorization of things be correct?

Tags: epistemology, ontology, concept, categorization

How/when can categorization of things be correct? Meaning just "categorization" in general.

It's intuitive that *categorization* is a "primitive" cognitive and linguistic phenomenon. Without categorization one couldn't distinguish between plants, animals, ...

However, there's an epistemological problem of:

**When can we know that a categorization is 'correct'?**

So if one labels something, how can one understand the validity of the categorization? Or also, if someone questions a categorical classification, then when can one interpret, whether the concern is "worthwhile"?

Again, perhaps intuitively, 'correct' may depend on:

- Social convention (if we have agreed on a particular category, it may be more easily accepted)
- An authority
- A "democratic" pattern (the majority decides correct category, or so)

Some people have argued (IMO, naively) about "fundamentality" of some categories, such as:

- Natural numbers

However, I'm not sure, whether there exists many fundamental categories. Some of them could be things that are physically measurable, e.g. pain, but this (reductive physicalism, basically) could be too limited. There have been also the philosophical ideas relating to:

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-kinds/

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/concepts/

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/

So what's categorization really? A multitude of things?

Perhaps motivated by these, one might also make a distinction between "belonging to a category/class" and the "class name". I.e. that the name of the class may be 'anything', but the reasons for "pairing things as belonging to a class" are "more fundamental, than mere semantics".

---

Possible answer:

A "pragmatist/realist" (as opposed to some abstract-idealist) could perhaps answer that

> a correct categorization is a combination of things that 'match up'
>   well with different 'measure' contexts (measurability, repeatability,
>   social-agreedness, ...).

So then it's somewhat similar to scientific method (?) A categorization is correct, if it behaves similarly to the scientific method (?) Scientific method is not "exact", but it's a collection and combination of things that "match up" and last for some time, so that people believe that "it's scientific".

Comment: This question excessively broad without context. Some related notions that can help you narrow your focus are [natural kinds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-kinds/), [concepts](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/concepts/), [categorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorization), and [definitions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/).

Comment: Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JD I think natural kinds, concepts, categorization and definitions would suffice for an answer?

Comment: It's important to reflect that categorization is an operation linked to [agency](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/agency/) and [intentionality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/). In that sense, it is intimately connected with [value theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/value-theory/) which is the idea that the operation of classification has some [teleological aspirations even at the biological level](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/teleology-biology/).

Comment: @JD Yes, but on the other hand, "objectivity" is sometimes an ideal of "scientific". Thus a scientific classification perhaps ought to avoid "personal value bias". Or, if bias is part of classification, then it could be mentioned and thus it would represent a different sorts of classification, than "ideal classification" (if such is feasible).

Comment: [Objectivity in science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectivity_(science)) is more of an ideal and tends to look towards personal value biases of various individuals canceling each other in the [intersubjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersubjectivity) process of peer-review, and doesn't eliminate personal value bias. In fact, the dominant position gravitates towards [underdetermination](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-underdetermination/) and [instrumentalist positions that are anti-realist](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-realism/#AntiFoilForScieReal).

Answer (score 1):

I would say a categorisation is always made from a point-of-view. In the end all things belong in the category 'everything' and how we divide them up after this is up to us. It all depends which features and properties of the object matter to us. Some we ignore, some we use as the basis of categorisation.

This would not mean that categories are arbitrary, just that they are a convention and a tool for thought, not a basic feature of the world. If a phenomenon is not in a category then we cannot think it, since it has no opposite from which it may be distinguished.

This problem arises in metaphysics for the totality as the totality cannot be a category. Thus we cannot think the totality and it lies beyond the intellect. This brings us to Russell's paradox and the impossibility of representing the whole as a category.

So, it's a deep topic. In metaphysics and meditation it is core curriculum stuff.

Comment: Yes, it's weird. On the other hand people come to agree on some categorizations for very long times. Therefore the form of some categories is "near scientific" in the sense that they seem consistent and long-lasting, similar to a physics theory. On the other hand some categorizations seem "up to be questioned", unless this could fall under "fallibilism" or something. So in essence, even if categorizations contained ambiguity, the ambiguity would be similar kind of "unlikeliness" as some physics theory failing. That it's so unlikely that it doesn't nec. pay to debate constantly over it.

Comment: I would also say it's based on point-of-view. But as I wrote, I've found that there exists claims about "fundamental categorizations" of some sort. Such as "natural numbers". I'd hold calling these "fundamental" to be a stretch, but yet the claims can be found. I.e. some people could be opposed to your viewpoint that "categories are not a feature of the world". They would claim that "we read those categories, which are fundamental features" or so. Is there a way to decide against "fundamental categories" as opposed to "a category is a social construct"? It's also possible that they're both.

Comment: @mavavilj - I think it depends on our purposes. In mathematics it's practical to say the natural numbers are fundamental in some sense, but in metaphysics it would be suicidal since a fundamental theory must reduce all categories. This is all about the relationship between the categories of thought and the nature of Reality and so it's not an easy topic. What is clear is that beyond metaphysics the word 'fundamental' is used in various inconsistent ways.    .

Comment: @mavavilj - I think we can say that we do use categories to describe features of the world, but that these features are not fundamental and must be sublated for a fundamental view of phenomena. Much in the manner of Kant. .